# Slack Conversations API conversations.kick returning "channel_not_found" for a public channel

Tags: slack-api, slack-bolt

I am writing a Slack integration that can boot certain users out of public channels when certain conditions are met. I have added several OAuth scopes to the bot token, including the following:

- channels:history
- channels:manage
- channels:read
- chat:write
- chat:write.public
- groups:write
- im:write
- mpim:write
- users:read

I am writing my bot in Python using the [slack-bolt library](https://github.com/SlackAPI/bolt-python) and asyncio. However when I try to invoke this code:

```py
await app.client.conversations_kick(channel=channel_id, user=user_id)
```

I get the following error:

```
slack_sdk.errors.SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed. (url: https://www.slack.com/api/conversations.kick)
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'channel_not_found'}
```

I know for a fact that both the `channel_id` and `user_id` arguments I'm passing in are valid. The channel ID I'm using is the string `C01PAE3DB0A`. I know it is valid because I can use the very same value for `channel_id` in the following API call:

```py
response = await app.client.conversations_info(channel=channel_id)
```

And when I call `conversations_info` like that I get all of the information about my channel. (The same is true for calling `users_info` with the `user_id` - it returns successfully.) So why is that when I pass my valid `channel_id` parameter to `conversations_kick` I consistently receive this `channel_not_found` error? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I got in touch directly with Slack support about this and they confirmed that there is a bug on their end. Specifically, the bug is that I should have received a `restricted_action` error response instead of a `channel_not_found` response. Apparently this is a known issue that is on their backlog.

The reason the API call would (try to) return this `restricted_action` error is simply because there is a workspace setting that, by default, prevents non-admins from kicking people out of public channels. Furthermore, this setting can only be changed by the workspace *owner* - one tier above admins.

But assuming you are the owner of the Slack workspace, you simply have to log into the [Settings & Permissions page](https://my.slack.com/admin/settings#channel_management_restrictions), which should look something like this:

[image: Channel management screenshot]

And then you have to change the setting labeled "People who can remove members from public channels" from "Workspace admins and owners only (default)" to "Everyone, except guests."

Once I made that change, my API calls started succeeding.

Comment: I had this exact same issue and thought I was going insane, thank you for the self answer.

Comment: Is possible to keep and remove only the workspace owner and let the also manage the members from a bot?